# Move full Ubuntu to another drive

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I currently use Ubuntu 20.04. on Lenovo laptop SSD 512 it have Boot mode -> BIOS.

I want to move existing Ubuntu to the new Laptop (and to have DualBoot) who has two drives on one is Windows 10 (boot mode -> UEFI) and on second I would like to have my Ubuntu with all the data.

What is the easiest (or the best) way to do this?

Comment: @FedKad not even close to what the OP asked. Please read the question.

Comment: While it might be possible to transfer an Ubuntu installation, I guess it should be easier and faster to reinstall and copy the data/settings you need.

Comment: You can create a partition image in the Ubuntu Disks application on your Lenovo laptop. Install Ubuntu on your new laptop. Use a USB stick or external drive to copy the image to your new laptop. After that, select "benchmark" and set it to restore onto your new laptop. It should also copy the properties.

If this doesn't work delete the /home directory on the new laptop, and copy the /home directory from the Lenovo to the new one. I'm not sure if this will work perfectly (I honestly don't think so, but if the first option doesn't work, just try it).

Comment: You cannot easily copy MBR(msdos) partition to gpt. Your gpt has unique GUIDs in primary partition table, backup partition table and every partition. Force copy of MBR partition then does not have correct GUID and may totally corrupt system. Better to do new install & restore from your normal backup. That would include at minimum your /home, your data and all your user settings are in /home. Also export of list of installed apps, to make it easy to reinstall any apps you added.